# I got error Cannot find module 'node:path' when installing laravel/vite app

Tags: npm

I tried to install laravel9/vite app on Ubuntu 18.04 on my remote host and got error:

```
root@nsn-do-lamp:/var/www/html/mng-products# npm -v
6.14.8
root@nsn-do-lamp:/var/www/html/mng-products# npm run  build

> @ build /var/www/html/mng-products
> vite build

failed to load config from /var/www/html/mng-products/vite.config.js
error during build:
Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'
Require stack:
- /var/www/html/mng-products/node_modules/vite/dist/node-cjs/publicUtils.cjs
- /var/www/html/mng-products/node_modules/vite/index.cjs
- /var/www/html/mng-products/vite.config.js
- /var/www/html/mng-products/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-74663fff.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/mng-products/node_modules/vite/dist/node-cjs/publicUtils.cjs:5:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object._require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (file:///var/www/html/mng-products/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-74663fff.js:63058:17)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! @ build: `vite build`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Failed at the @ build script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-09-21T11_26_59_040Z-debug.log


root@nsn-do-lamp:/var/www/html/mng-products# cat /var/www/html/mng-products/vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

        export default defineConfig({
        plugins: [
        laravel({
        input: [
        'resources/css/app.css',
        'resources/js/app.js',
        ],
        refresh: true,
        }),
        ],
        });

root@nsn-do-lamp:/var/www/html/mng-products# node -v
        v14.15.1

root@nsn-do-lamp:/var/www/html/mng-products# whereis node
        node: /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/include/node /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz

root@nsn-do-lamp:/var/www/html/mng-products# lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
        Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
        4.15.0-192-generic
        x86_64
```

Any ideas how it can be fixed ?

my OS :

```
root@nsn-do-lamp:/var/www/html/mng-products# uname -a
Linux nsn-do-lamp 4.15.0-192-generic #203-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 10 17:40:03 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@nsn-do-lamp:/var/www/html/mng-products# 
root@nsn-do-lamp:/var/www/html/mng-products# lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
4.15.0-192-generic
```

Thanks!

Comment: you probably need to do `npm install` first.

Comment: Sure I run npm install firstly

Comment: I added my OS info

Comment: I'd also update your system if you are online; if you refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/ you'll see when 18.04.6 was released; with installed systems upgrading a ~week before the ISO release date which is what the release signifies.  Your additional details just show you're behind on security fixes & patches.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to upgrade to ubuntu 20?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 will upgrade to 20.04, only 18 upgrades to 20 (the *year* (18) and *year.month* (18.04) represent different Ubuntu products.  You say your system is 18.04.5 which means you're a year maybe more behind on security fixes; as a 18.04 system reported itself as 18.04.6 (not 18.04.5) back in September 2021.  My prior comment was suggesting you check your system is fully-upgraded (*either it isn't, **or** your 18.04.5 detail was incorrect*!)

Comment: That is not from my prior expierence. Could youi please show valid steps I have to take ?

Answer (score 1):

What does `node -v` give you?

I had the same error - due to an old version of node (v14.17.3) when the stable version as of now is v18.12.1

I resolved my issue by downloading the latest stable version from https://nodejs.org/en/download/